# Difference in testing between strongly-typed and weakly-typed languages

Tags: node.js, swift, unit-testing, types

I came from JS world and I am used to do thorough testing of all the possible cases that can be a result of weak typing. That way, inside a function I check all the incoming parameters to conform to some criteria.

As an example, in `function createUser(username, id, enabled, role){}` I would check if `username` is a string, `id` is a UUID, `status` is boolean, and role is a string that must be 'admin', 'user' or 'system'.

I create tests for these cases to make sure that when I pass wrong parameters, tests fail and I need to find bugs that lead to this. At the end, I have quite a lot of tests, many of which are type-checking tests.

Now, I am playing with Swift which is strongly-typed. I use it to create a client app that consumes data from a NodeJS server side. If I want to create a similar `createUser()` function in Swift, it seems like I need much less tests because type checking is in the language itself.

Is it right to think that a basically a strongly-typed language needs less tests than a weakly-typed one? Some tests just seem to be unnecessary in Swift and the whole test process seems to be more lightweight.

Are there things I can do to write even less tests by using language constructs in some specific manner and still be sure the code is correct and would pass tests by definition?

Answer (score 0):

The use of 
optionals and non-optionals, guard, if let
may save you some nil checks

for example - 
Guard Statement

A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope if one or more conditions aren’t met.

A guard statement has the following form:

guard condition else {
    statements
}

and more generally, read this - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html